Getting longest line from a list of lines
I have the following problem:
In a list of lines (separated by \\), how to get the longest line; or at the very least, the width of the longest line.
I see that there is a Plain TeX solution --- which I do not understand --- here: How to set paragraph width as the width of the longest line.
Is there a more user-friendly LaTeXy solution?


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
         One line\\
         another longer line\\
         short\\
         1\\
         2\\
         333\\
       \end{tabular}}

The longest line is \the\wd0
\end{document}


note I answered the question as asked, but usually  you don't need this length, you can just use the tabular directly, eg to centre the block on the longest line just use the tabular in a center environment
